# In Search of a map $\phi:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ satisfying additivity.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying without much luck to come up with an example of a function $\phi:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ such that $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x)+\phi(y),\forall x,y\in\mathbf{C}$ and yet for some $a,\alpha\in\mathbf{C}$ we have $\phi(a\alpha)\neq a\phi(\alpha)$.

Any hints on how to get me started?

Comment: Does it have to be continuous? Does it have to be holomorphic? These are questions and hints :)

Comment: @SteveD It is not specified so i guess it does not matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this ?$$\phi:z \mapsto \overline{z}$$

Answer (score 1):

As for hints, a standard thing to try in functional equations is to plug in nice values. For example, $\phi(0)=\phi(0+0)=\phi(0)+\phi(0)$, hence $\phi(0)=0$. Similar steps allow you to conclude $\phi\left(\frac{m}{n}x\right)=\frac{m}{n}\phi(x)$ for any integers $m$ and $n$ and any complex $x$. In other words, your function is at least linear over the rationals.

Such functions **do actually exist**, but they're really awful. They even exist [over the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation#Existence_of_nonlinear_solutions_over_the_real_numbers). Part of the problem in finding an example is that over the rationals any additive function is also linear. One implication of this is that any **continuous** additive function is also linear.

Comment: The answer above (@Chinnapparaj R) shows that for Gaussian rationals additive functions need not be linear.